# How to use OffscreenCanvas in TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, canvas

I'd like to use OffscreenCanvas in a typescript project, but I have no idea how to do this. When I try:

```
let offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);
```

my ide says "Cannot find name OffscreenCanvas".

Any hints ?

Comment: It seems `OffscreenCanvas` currently lacks [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I use firefox, and the line runs when in js file. I meant that my typescript ide  can't find OffscreenCanvas definition and can't compile ts file to js.

Answer (score 20):

You can install `@types/offscreencanvas` to your project.

**Yarn**

```sh
yarn add @types/offscreencanvas
```

**npm**

```sh
npm i @types/offscreencanvas
```

Now enjoy it!

For more https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/offscreencanvas

Comment: It cannot help me in my case. "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd": "~2.0.0", "@tensorflow/tfjs": "~1.3.2", "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "~1.3.2", "@types/offscreencanvas": "^2019.6.0"

Comment: To make the error go away, I had also to add the type in my tsconfig.json, like this: `"types": [ "node", "offscreencanvas" ]`

Answer (score 3):

For the time being, you'll need to modify your `lib.dom.d.ts` or similar.

In `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`, find `interface HTMLCanvasElement extends HTMLElement` and append the lines

```ts
interface HTMLCanvasElement extends HTMLElement {
    // ...
    transferControlToOffscreen(): OffscreenCanvas;
}

interface OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D extends CanvasState, CanvasTransform, CanvasCompositing, CanvasImageSmoothing, CanvasFillStrokeStyles, CanvasShadowStyles, CanvasFilters, CanvasRect, CanvasDrawPath, CanvasUserInterface, CanvasText, CanvasDrawImage, CanvasImageData, CanvasPathDrawingStyles, CanvasTextDrawingStyles, CanvasPath {
    readonly canvas: OffscreenCanvas;
}
declare var OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D: {
    prototype: OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D;
    new(): OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D;
}
interface OffscreenCanvas extends EventTarget {
    width: number;
    height: number;
    getContext(contextId: "2d", contextAttributes?: CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings): OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D | null;
}
declare var OffscreenCanvas: {
    prototype: OffscreenCanvas;
    new(width: number, height: number): OffscreenCanvas;
}
```

And finally, edit the `Transferable` definitions in `lib.dom.d.ts` and `lib.webworker.d.ts`:

```ts
type Transferable = ArrayBuffer | MessagePort | ImageBitmap | OffscreenCanvas;
```

At that point, you'll have worked up the functions to change everything.

Also note: `OffscreenCanvas`s' `width` and `height` members are modifiable, and when using `canvas.transferControlToOffscreen()` the `width` and `height` of the element will be synchronised on the next frame if changed.

Note that this does not work with webgl contexts as that's a little more in-depth. Or rather, there's so much to copy that it makes no sense to unless you're trying to set it up.

This is hacky, but works. Ideally, you would go back through and make a PR on the typescript thing but right now this is more than enough.

Comment: If you do as suggested because you like living on the edge, be ware you will ofc have to do it again if you update Typescript.

Comment: image how annoying this is when you go to make the change based on VS Code hints, and you later realize you've been modifying the typescript definition files for VS Code, not the ones in node_modules your project uses to build. Having to edit those files directly in the typescript lib is really bad. I think there's a way to do hinting project level you can bundle with your source until typescript gets support, but I haven't gotten that working yet.

Comment: If you need to update to support OffscreenCanvas, it's available in typescript@next as of 9 days ago. I suggest updating to that version as a starting point.

Answer (score -5):

All variables need a type definition in Typescript, that's why it's called Typescript.
When we don't have type definitions for an object, we can define the type ourselves, or use any:
`let offscreen: any = new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);`

Note that using any is discouraged in Typescript, if you do it for every variable you may as well not use Typescript.

Read about declaration files here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html