# Any way to override a "type"(not interface) in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add definition of OffscreenCanvas following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53603401/3016883).

I don't want to modify `lib.dom.d.ts`, so I put the definition in an external `custom.d.ts` and get an error:

```
type Transferable = ArrayBuffer | MessagePort | ImageBitmap | OffscreenCanvas;
     ^
     Duplicate identifier 'Transferable'.
```

Is there any way to redefine the type "Transferable"?

Comment: No, they have to adapt `Transferable` type definition following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52416170/43848) for you to be able to do that.